# PySpark explode json array issue in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am consuming an api json payload and create a table in Azure Databricks using PySpark explode array and map columns to rows so that the results are tabular with columns & rows.

***JSON:***

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "New Company",
            "Flag": "1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "Old Company",
            "Flag": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

PySpark explode works as below.

```
dataframe.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("petbl")
```

***Result:***

| Id | Name | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Company | 1 |
| One | Old Company | 0 |

When I use the below code the json code remains the same as a string in the table with the data column and 1 row with all the json array.

```
dataframe.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("path","abfss://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/<file_name>").saveAsTable("petbl")
```

How to keep the tabular data format intact even after running the above command instead of having a JSON string?